# Play- Why split a string using comma from string to list is not working properly?

Tags: java, string, playframework-2.0

I have a string type list with one value. In that field, the value is like this:

> list1[0]:yes,no,never,drop out

There are some comma. I have to split them by comma and add them in different list,like:

> list2[0] : yes
>
> list2[1] : no
>
> list2[3] : never
>
> list2[4] : drop out

To do this, at first, I have converted list1 to string and then split them with comma and save them in 2nd list.

But after converting string, the string is:

string : [yes,no,never,drop out]

and 2nd list is finally:

> list2[0] : [yes
>
> list2 [1] : no
>
> list2[3] : never
>
> list2[4] : drop out]

[image: the terminal screenshot is given]

Here is my controller code:

```
@ExternalRestrictions("Edit Poll")
    public static void editPoll(Long id){

        PollDefination poll = PollDefination.findById(id);
        flash("poll", "" + poll.id);
        List<String> pollQuestionOption = PollQuestionOption.find("SELECT options from PollQuestionOption WHERE poll_id = ? ", poll.id).fetch();

        for (int i = 0; i < pollQuestionOption.size(); i++) {
            Logger.info("1st list : " + pollQuestionOption.get(i).toString());
        }

        String option = pollQuestionOption.toString();

        Logger.info("string : " + option);

        List<String> optionitem = Arrays.asList(option.split(","));

        Logger.info("2nd list : " + optionitem);
        List<String> questionType = new ArrayList<String>();
        questionType.add(0,"Single Select");
        questionType.add(1,"Multiple Select");
        render(questionType,poll,pollQuestionOption,optionitem);
    }
```

and here is my html:

```
 #{list items: optionitem, as:'optionitem'}

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="addField">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                      <div class="input-group">

                                        <input name="optionitem" type="text" class="form-control" id="optionitem" value="${optionitem}" placeholder="Option">

                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                             <button href="#" class="removeOption">
                                              <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x text-danger" style="font-size: 18px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                             </button>
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                #{/list}
```

And now the value is shown like this:

[image]

[image: here is my database]

How can I avoid this "[" and "]" ?

Comment: You already have a list stored in `pollQuestionOption`: why transforming it to string and then split it again? What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you just use `pollQuestionOption`?

Comment: How I can split a list with comma?

Comment: Did you read my comment? Can you answer my questions?

Comment: list1[0]:yes,no,never,drop out , this is a list. I have to split them and add them in separate , like as:


    list2[0] : yes

    list2[1] : no

    list2[3] : never

    list2[4] : drop out

-where list1 size is 1 and list2 size is 4

Comment: A list works like an array. `pollQuestionOption` already has those values. Commas are added just for printing purposes, but you can access the values via `pollQuestionOption.get(0)`, `pollQuestionOption.get(1)`, etc.

Comment: pollQuestionOption has only one value. the value is : "yes,no,never,drop out " . I have added screenshot of my database. please chq it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first List is

```
List<String>_list0 = "yes,no,never,drop out"
```

Do this:

```
List<String> _list1 = Arrays.asList(_list0.get(0).split(","));
System.out.println(_list1.toString());
_list1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And you will have no brackets in your new List. System.out shows that

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String option = pollQuestionOption.toString();
```

to

```
String option = pollQuestionOption.get(0).toString();
```